# How to run a simple pytest-bdd test with pywinauto?

Tags: python, pytest, pywinauto

I am trying to set up a pytest-bdd pywinauto test, but I can't get it to work.

I failed to find any simple examples with pywinauto. The official documentation of pytest-bdd only has one selenium example, but I cannot understand it, since I am not familiar with it.

This is my project structure, just two files in the same folder:
foo.feature
test_foo.py

This is `foo.feature` file content:

```
Feature: Type stuff

   The user should be able to type stuff into notepad.

    Scenario: Type a sentence
        Given Application object exists
        When I start notepad
        And Focus on the window
        And I type some stuff
        Then Typed stuff should be visible
```

This is `test_foo.py` file content:

```py
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys


@scenario('foo.feature', 'Type a sentence')
def test_foo():
    pass


@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    return Application()


@given("Application object exists")
def app_exists(app):
    assert 'app' in locals()


@when("I start notepad")
def start_notepad(app):
    app.start("notepad.exe")


@when("Focus on the window")
def notepad_focus(app):
    app.top_window().set_focus()


@when("I type some stuff")
def type_stuff():
    send_keys("Hello, world!", with_spaces=True)


@then("Typed stuff should be visible")
def typed_stuff_visible(app):
    edit_field = app.top_window().window(class_name='Edit')
    assert edit_field.texts()[0] == 'Hello, world!'
```

For some reason I can't get "then" fixture to work. The test fails with this error:

```
E   pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: When "I type some stuff
E   Then Typed stuff should be visible". Line 9 in scenario "Type a sentence" in the feature "C:\Users\...\foo.feature
```

If I remove "then" test from `foo.feature` file, the test runs and the text gets typed into notepad. For some reason "then" messes it up completely and nothing gets typed into the editor.

Comment: Hi Joe, did you find a way to do so?
If yes, I would be interested to know it! :)